# Brackets live preview with php file

Tags: php, adobe-brackets, live-preview

I discovered the editor "brackets" yesterday and tried to get it working. Now I have some trouble with the live preview, which does not seem to cooperate with php files. 
I opened my folder, selected the index.php and when I clicked on live preview it requested for a base url (I am running brackets version 1.7 on windows 8.1 if this is of any relevance). I have also read some instructions about this problem here, but it all leads to the consequence that it isn't possible to actually use live preview but only local servers with php files. Does anyone perhaps have a solution for this?

Most of the instructions I read are already a little bit old so perhaps it is somehow possible now (preferably without needing a local server). I have heard so many positive things about the editor, I am actually really eager to use it.

Comment: Having a similar problem - I know the fix, but I cannot find the file to carry it out. Check out [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536163/mac-osx-adobe-brackets-cannot-find-js-file-to-edit-statichtmlfileexts). The first [link](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5058#issuecomment-37831703) in the question shows how you'd modify `_staticHtmlFileExts` to force Brackets to show preview for PHP files without a local server set up. The preview won't actually be "live". Let me know if you figure out where the file to edit is.

Comment: @birrel thanks man, but I'm already too far over time to try it out, I just went with XAMPP and do it locally with php now. But still thanks again! Will have a look at it at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with a local solution for now