# Mac OSX, Adobe Brackets - Cannot find file (JS, part of Brackets) to edit "_staticHtmlFileExts"

Tags: macos, adobe-brackets

*Sorry if this isn't the place for this, I don't know where else I'd ask.*

**For Mac OSX El Capitan**

I am trying to edit the property `_staticHtmlFileExts`

The variable used to be defined in [src/file/FileUtils.js](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/5058#issuecomment-37831703), but has since been moved to [src/LiveDevelopment/LiveDevelopmentUtils.js](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/LiveDevelopment/LiveDevelopmentUtils.js).

When I go to `Show Developer Tools` within Brackets, I can view the sources, and very easily find `/LiveDevelopment/` (and the child JS file)...

[image: DevToolsSources]

But any changes I make to the file are not saves on the system, and thus do not persist on successive opens of the Brackets app.

When I try to find the same file on my system, it is nowhere to be found...

[image: MacOSNoDirectory]

I have hidden folders set to display (which they all do, when present), so I do not believe this to be the issue.

How come I can view the files in the `Dev Tools`, but not on my system? How, or where, can I make the change permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build installed with the `Brackets.dmg` installed minified, concatenated source file (`main.js` under `~/Application/Brackets.app/Contents/www/`) along with a [source map](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), which is why you can see the sources in developer tools, but you cannot see the original source files.

See the article [How to hack on Brackets](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Hack-on-Brackets) for instructions on setting up a development environment if you want to modify the files themselves.

For reference, the steps are as follows:

1. Install the latest Brackets build (this gives you the native shell binaries which you'll use in step 6)
2. Fork the brackets repo
3. Clone your fork of the repo: `git clone https://github.com/<username>/brackets`
4. Fetch submodules: `cd brackets && git submodule update --init`
5. Add an "upstream" remote: `git remote add upstream https://github.com/adobe/brackets`
6. Run setup_for_hacking script with `tools/setup_for_hacking.sh "/Applications/Brackets.app"`

Note that the steps 2 and 3 are optional if you are just making modifications for yourself. If so, you can just clone straight from the master (`git clone https://github.com/adobe/brackets`).

Comment: Ok, yeah I saw the hacking guide already. I was hoping there was something I could do to modify the files directly, to avoid the whole setup with git and what not.

Comment: You can do modifications for the minified file too, but it is not exactly easy: your best bet is to do them via the developer tools. Also note that that way your changes will be nuked when a new version of Brackets is released

Comment: Where are the minified files to modify? I'm not too worried about the nuking thing for now.

Comment: There's only one file, `~/Application/Brackets.app/Contents/www/main.js` which contains everything.

Comment: Oh man, what a bummer. It's huge, and obfuscated, and everything is surrounded in an `eval`, but then the contents have their own deals surrounding them. What a headache!

Comment: Yep, you're right. Was able to do a string search to find and change `_staticHtmlFileExts`, but either Brackets, or my browser, or this brick of a computer didn't like it too much. I've only had headaches from this software since I've started trying it out.